# Please solve by elimination method.

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $a,b,c,d ⊆ R$, if $$a \sec(200°) - c \tan(200°) = d$$ and $$b \sec(200°) + d \tan(200°) = c$$ then find the value of $$\dfrac {(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)(\sin 20°)}{(bd-ac)}.$$
I got the relation of c^2+d^2.

Comment: What have you tried? As you are new to this site, I can tell you that people here expect questions that already show what you have tried and where you are stuck. This is not a homework-solving site.

Comment: "sim" looks like a typo, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\sec(200^{\circ})=A$$ and $$\tan(200^{\circ})=B$$ then our system is given by 
$$aA-cB=d$$
$$Ab+Bd=c$$
From the second equation we get
$$aA-(Ab+BdB)B=d$$ solving for $d$ we obtain
$$d=\frac{aA-ABb}{B^2+1}=\frac{A(a-Bb)}{B^2+1}$$
using this equation we get $c$:
$$c=\frac{A(Ba-b)}{B^2+1}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Yes i got answer 2

Answer (score 0):

Let $200^\circ=t$

multiply out both relations by $\cos t$ to find

$$b\sin t+d\cos t=a$$

$$-d\sin t+c\cos t=b$$

Solve for $\sin t$